# Chrome graphical distortion after hardware acceleration disabled

Tags: gnome, graphics, google-chrome

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and Chrome was flickering (an issue I also had while using Elementary OS), so I read online that this has something to do with hardware acceleration, so I disabled it. It worked and the flickers disappeared. To my surprise, however, weird lines started to appear (or actually more like distorting text and images). It's not as bad as the flickering, since it doesn't happen as often, but it is still fairly annoying.

Here's an image of what I'm exactly experiencing:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you have a Skylake GPU (Intel Core ix-6xxx), then this is currently an issue and there are no concrete fixes. Please report bugs at Launchpad. In addition,@Moksh, please do not post comments affirming the bug, simply upvote the question. Your use of Linux Mint is also irrelevant here in AskUbuntu.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Do you know if it only occurs in Chrome or other browsers as well? It might be another reason to switch to Opera (other than the free integrated VPN hah)

Comment: I am not aware of it affecting any other browsers. I generally tolerate the artifacts- they aren't a big issue.

Comment: I can confirm it affects Opera as well. Maybe not as bad though...